# Shuffle an array of images jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i would like to shuffle an array of images with jquery.The problem is that 'till now i did something which doesnt show images ...it shows only path for them.Where i was wrong?

Code here:

HTML:

```
<div id="array" class="thirdcanvas"></div>
<button class="array">Shuffle</button>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(function($){

$(document).ready( function() 
{ 
    $('#array').shuffle(); 
}); 

    var arr = new Array("images/alfabet/a.png", "images/alfabet/b.png", "images/alfabet/c.png", "images/alfabet/e.png", "images/alfabet/f.png");
    $('#array').text(arr.join(", "));
    $('button.array').click(function(){
        arr = $.shuffle(arr);
        $('#array').text(arr.join(", "));

    });
});

var image6 = new Image();
   image6.src = "images/alfabet/a.png";
   var image7 = new Image();
   image7.src = "images/alfabet/b.png";
   var image8 = new Image();
   image8.src = "images/alfabet/c.png";
   var image9 = new Image();
   image9.src = "images/alfabet/e.png";
   var image10 = new Image();
   image10.src = "images/alfabet/f.png";



(function($){

    $.fn.shuffle = function() {
        return this.each(function(){
            var items = $(this).children().clone(true);
            return (items.length) ? $(this).html($.shuffle(items)) : this;
        });
    };

    $.shuffle = function(arr) {
        for(var j, x, i = arr.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = arr[--i], arr[i] = arr[j], arr[j] = x);
        return arr;
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    var arr = new Array("//placehold.it/32/ff0000.png", "//placehold.it/32/00ff00.png", "//placehold.it/32/0000ff.png", "//placehold.it/32/ff00ff.png", "//placehold.it/32/00ffff.png");

    $.each($.shuffle(arr), function (_, src) {
        $('<img />', {
            src: src
        }).appendTo('#array')
    })
    $('button.array').click(function () {
        $('#array').shuffle()
    });
});

(function ($) {

    $.fn.shuffle = function () {
        var _self = this,
            children = $.shuffle(this.children().get());
        $.each(children, function () {
            _self.append(this)
        })
        return this;
    };

    $.shuffle = function (arr) {
        for (var j, x, i = arr.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = arr[--i], arr[i] = arr[j], arr[j] = x);
        return arr;
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/R2fNC/)

Answer (score 1):

This code goes in your click listener and creates images with the srcs from the array. You can then remove your `new Image()`s. This is not an efficient implementation, but it's fine for a small page. It involves the minimum changes to your original code.

```
$('button.array').click(function () {
    arr = $.shuffle(arr);
    $('#array').text(arr.join(", "));

    // Added:
    $(".thirdcanvas").html(""); // empties container
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length ;i++){
        // Add an image
        $(".thirdcanvas").append($("<img src='" + arr[i] + "'>"));
    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answear,i tryed @Arun P Johny code and it works great

Comment: @OzZie Good to hear. Then you should accept his answer by clicking on the tick.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have all the parts you need there. We just need to take the image links and create `<img>` elements from them, then append them to the `<div>`. The shuffle function can then be called directly on the `<div>`, to shuffle the images in place, without having to use the original array again.

Something like:

```
$(document).ready( function() { 
    var arr = new Array("http://placehold.it/50x50&text=a", "ihttp://placehold.it/50x50&text=b", "http://placehold.it/50x50&text=c", "http://placehold.it/50x50&text=d", "http://placehold.it/50x50&text=e");

    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
      var img = new Image();
      img.src = arr[i];
      $('#array').append(img);
    }

    $('button.array').click(function(){
      $('#array').shuffle();
    });
});

(function($){

    $.fn.shuffle = function() {
        return this.each(function(){
            var items = $(this).children().clone(true);
            return (items.length) ? $(this).html($.shuffle(items)) : this;
        });
    };

    $.shuffle = function(arr) {
        for(var j, x, i = arr.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = arr[--i], arr[i] = arr[j], arr[j] = x);
        return arr;
    };

})(jQuery);
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ygaw2/

This uses a for loop to iterate across the array of links, so the array can contain as many links as required.

Answer (score 1):

You never create `<img>` elements, that's why you only see the URL.
Here's the code you should use:

```js
// your bunch of pictures
var arr = new Array(
    "http://placehold.it/100x100", 
    "http://placehold.it/120x100", 
    "http://placehold.it/140x100", 
    "http://placehold.it/160x100", 
    "http://placehold.it/180x100"
);

// Refresh pictures
function refreshPictures() {
    // Create new DOM element    
    var pictures = $('<ul id="pictures"></ul>');
    for(var i=0, n=arr.length; i<n; i++) {
        pictures.append('<li><img src="'+arr[i]+'"/></li>');
    }
    // Replace current element by new one
    $('#pictures').replaceWith(pictures);
}

// Add click listener on #randomize button
$('#randomize').on('click', function(){
    arr = arr.shuffle();
    refreshPictures();
});

// Initialize pictures
refreshPictures();

// Add shuffle() function to Array prototype
Array.prototype.shuffle = function() {
    for(var j, x, i = this.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = this[--i], this[i] = this[j], this[j] = x);
    return this;
};
```

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    float: left;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="pictures"></ul>
<button id="randomize">Shuffle</button>
```

Comment: Thx for your answer <3 i'm sorry i cant vote all of em up coz i tested all and works great...but im newbie and i dont have enough reputation :(

Comment: You should accept some answers when you consider it correct, and sometimes provide anwers. This will give you reputation and new rights on SO.